# How to save all the output from a .ipynb file as a txt file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, txt

I have a few .ipynb notebooks with similar outputs (time series data). I want to export all the outputs from all the notebooks to a .txt file. If that is complicated to do, then one txt file for each of the notebooks is fine too.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how your data is outputted? Are they numpy arrays, lists, pandas DataFrames, ...?

Comment: It is outputed as a pandas dataframe.

Comment: I have tried this.

'%%capture cap --no-stderr
print(xyz)'

'with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(cap.stdout)'

However, the output dataframe of one of the notebooks, for example, has 6032 rows x 158 columns. And the txt file created only shows the first few rows as when you print it in the jupyter notebook. But I need all of the output dataframe rows to be included in the txt file. @icdumort

Comment: I think you could use this `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None) `, however 6032 is really a lot. I'm not sure if it will be decently displayed

Comment: Thank you. Do I use this along with the code I mentioned? If so, which cell should I add this code in?

Comment: This would be a pandas settings, so ideally immediately after importing your packages. The rest of your code remains unaltered. Once you've ran it, the setting remains unchanged until you change it manually or restart the kernel/notebook

Comment: Thank you so much :). This worked. I used it here:

%%capture cap --no-stderr 
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
print(xyz)

Comment: you're welcome! I've summarized our discussion in an answer for other people to easily follow up. If it worked for you, feel free to select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned yourself in the comments, you can save it as a .txt file by using:

```py
%%capture cap --no-stderr
```

By using `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)` you can then assure that all rows are shown in your jupyter notebook.